# Using Fonts in an Azure-Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I try to get PdfSharp working in an Azure Function
But I have some problems with fonts

```
 // Create a new PDF document
  PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
  document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";

  // Create an empty page
  PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

  // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
  XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

  // Create a font
  XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);

  // Draw the text
  gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black,
    new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
    XStringFormats.Center);
```

This is also the code from the PDFSharp sample page...
At the font line he gives me the following error...

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.PDFGenerationFunction. PdfSharp: Internal error. Font data could not retrieved.
```

Do I need to reference something special? Or is it just not possible to do this in an Azure function?

PDFSharp version -->  "PDFsharp" : "1.32.3057"

And/Or another solution to generate a PDF document in an Azure Function...

Comment: As answered elsewhere: Azure Functions (which run in the context of a Web App) is sandboxed, and you cannot install certain software (activex etc).

Answer (score 2):

This is likely an issue with the sandbox that Azure Functions and webapps run in. 
Check out this list for known PDF libraries that will work in the sandbox. 
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks

Comment: Also any examples with a Library that just can create an empty Pdf and put in the document some plain text..

Comment: Does anyone know if Google Cloud Functions have this dreadful limitation?

Answer (score 0):

PDF Sharp is unable to find an appropriate font for the function and also for Web APIs/Apps. Because they are not provided with the standard fonts.

To resolve this one needs to code and provide a *font resolver* based on the PDFSharp interface `IFontResolver` to PDF Sharp. That resolver will actually acquire the font and return it as a stream.

The below example is a resolver I wrote to extract from the current assemblies embeded fonts such as:

```
PdfSharp.Fonts.GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver = new EmbeddedFontResolver();
```

---

The best example on how to create such a resolver on Stack Overflow is this answer (*it is not my answer, but I have modified it to provide a better understanding of what happens*)

[Azure PDF Sharp not using Unicode font](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32980927/285795)

If the function won't allow you to use embeded fonts, you can load them most likely from an Azure Blob.