# Problem rendering µ and ³ with MigraDoc (PdfSharp) in Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, migradoc

I'm rendering a PDF using MigraDocCore, when I run my app locally these symbols render correctly:

[image: Symbols rendering correctly when running locally]

But when I run it in Azure App Service the symbols are missing:

[image: Symbols rendering incorrectly in Azure]

My default Style is defined as

```
Style style = Document.Styles["Normal"];
style.Font.Name = "Arial";
style.Font.Color = Colors.Black;
style.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = Unit.FromMillimeter(5);
```

Why are these symbols not rendering correctly in Azure and how can I fix it?

---- Edit:
I've just noticed as I post this that the one of the m³ is rendering correctly in Azure, while others aren't.

[image: Grab showing one ³ symbol working in Azure while others don't]

The difference here is that the one's not working are hard coded strings while the one that does work is going through the Localizer.

e.g.

```
var tf = section.AddTextFrame();

// This works
var str = L("m³");
var para = tf.AddParagraph(str);

// This doesn't work
var para = tf.AddParagraph("m³");
```

If I check the character code of the hard coded `³` and the one in my localization json they're both char 179.

The only difference I can see here is the json file is UTF-8 without the BOM, while the .cs file is ~~UTF-8 with a BOM~~ Western European. (This is probably going to be the issue).

I've saved the .cs file as UTF-8 without the BOM and will report back...

Comment: use the following steps
1. Install the WPF build of 'PDFsharp' 1.50 beta 2 from NuGet
2. Use a Font Resolver to select the font Using private fonts with 'PDFsharp' 1.50 beta 2 or 'MigraDoc'
3. Add the 'unicode' font as an embedded resource in the project.
Refer: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32980927/15997690)

Comment: Files without BOM may be interpreted in different ways depending on the regional settings of the computer. There was a time when PDFsharp/MigraDoc did not compile in China because some *.cs files did not have the BOM. Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, need to use the below steps:

1. Install the WPF build of PDFsharp 1.50 beta 2 from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PDFsharp-MigraDoc-WPF/1.50.3915-beta2)
2. Use a Font Resolver to select the font [Using private fonts with PDFsharp 1.50 beta 2 or MigraDoc](http://developer.th-soft.com/developer/using-private-fonts-with-pdfsharp-1-50-beta-2-or-migradoc/)
3. Add the unicode font as an embedded resource in the project.

The similar type of font issue in PDFSharp refer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32980927/15997690)